# Is "trivial" a suitable word to describe a low-class car?

Tags: word-usage

"Trivial" means "having little value or importance," but I'm not sure if it is an appropriate word to describe a low-class car in the following sentence.

> My car's too **trivial** to have such facilities.

Comment: I think [**basic**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/basic) is a better description. The car itself may be 'essential' - quite the opposite of 'trivial'.

Comment: Inappropriate, perhaps, but funny.

Comment: In my opinion it would be some of the extra facilities included in higher specification vehicles which would be 'trivial' I don't see the need for sophisticated 'infotainment' systems for example.